# Android: Leave one activity running when page is called multiple times

Tags: android, android-activity

I have multiple pages branching of a title page, and when a back button is pressed on the branch pages it recalls the title page with:

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent(Options.this, TitlePage.class);
        Options.this.startActivity(backIntent);
```

Then destroys with:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

The problem is each time this is called it overlays the title page. I need only one title page to exist without destroying all of them with the finish() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
bachIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Comment: This is for when you specifically launch an intent. I think what you need to do is add this to your manifest <activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" />  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Right, the manifest code is for when you cant/dont launch the intent(like from a program launcher).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your branching activities to go back to the title activity no matter how far down the tree the user goes, you should call those activities with the [`noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) flag. That way, anytime the child activities are finished, the user will always end up back at the title activity.

This can be done two ways:

**With the `Intent` used to launch the `Activity`:**

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(this, myIntent);
```

**In the Android Manifest file (`AndroidManifest.xml`):**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.logitech.squeezebox.activities.HomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```